# javascript plain text url parsing

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, url-parsing

I'm trying to search plain old strings for urls that begin with http, but all the regex I find doesn't seem to work in javascript nor can I seem to find an example of this in javascript.

This is the one I'm trying to use from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341942/recognize-url-in-plain-text) and [here](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/):

```
var test = /\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]/;
```

But when I try to run it, I get "Unexpected token |" errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a comment seems to be not enough, hard to find full answer. I rewrite whole proper regexp: (tested, it works good)

```
var test = /\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i;
```

The `i` on the end means 'ignore case', so it is necessary for this regexp.

Comment: Might be useful to note that adding a | before www will make the www optional.

Comment: This will fail on url's with parentheses

Answer (score 0):

You're using `/` as your regex delimiter, and are also using `/` within the regex (before www), so the regex actually terminates after the first / before www. Change it to:

```
var test = /\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]/;
                                     ^^^^ escape here
```

Comment: forgot to mention, this regexp is case insensitive, so you would rather write this: `var test = /\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i;`