# How to replace url if it is not anchored yet?

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I need to replace all urls in the text IF they are not put into '...' HTML tags yet.

The unconditional way to replace is described here: [Recognize URL in plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341942/recognize-url-in-plain-text).

Here is my implementation of it:

```
    private static readonly Regex UrlMatcherRegex = new Regex(@"\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    public static string GetProcessedMessage(this INews news)
    {
        string res = UrlMatcherRegex.Replace(news.Mess, ReplaceHrefByAnchor);

        return res;
    }

    private static string ReplaceHrefByAnchor(Match match)
    {
        string href = match.Groups[0].Value;
        return string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">{0}</a>", href);
    }
```

But how can I ignore those URLs which are already formatted properly?

Please advise.

P.S. I'm using ASP.NET 4.5

P.P.S. I could imagine that one of the solutions could be enhance regex to check for "

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view there are 2 solutions:

1. Use special libraries to parse your HTML document (if it's proper HTML document). For example, you can use [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx). After parsing the document you can easily find out if the element is normal HTML "a" tag or it's just a plain text.
2. You can suggest that if the link is already formatted properly - it will have "href" prefix before the URL. So, in your regex you can search for all links not having "href=" before them. This could be done either via C# or via regex negative look-around functionality. You can see an example here: [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)